# Linux Mint 13 can't detect SSD &/or Windows 7

Tags: windows, system-installation, dual-boot, ssd

I'm a newcomer to Linux OSes in general. I'm trying to install Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon alongside Windows 7. Linux Mint can't seem to see/detect either of my SSDs and because of that, it can't read/detect Windows 7.

So how do I get Linux to read my SSDs without installing Linux first? And if that doesn't happen, how can I install Linux so that it appears in that "choose OS" list in the boot menu?

Comment: What is the disk configuration in your BIOS? I had this problem with Fedora not recognizing the format and I needed to set my SATA III disks up in AHCI format before Linux would recognize it.

Comment: I switched from ide to ahci but then i couldnt boot from the cd. so i switched back to ide. should i try booting from a usb?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, when you switch from IDE to AHCI and your DVD Drive is SATA based, you have to modify the Boot information as it changed to a different path. (not sure if you did that). Also, once you are in AHCI, Windows won't boot...so I guess I should just say now that I think you are going to have a really difficult time doing this.